# Processing manifest failed android studio

Tags: android-studio, manifest

I have an issue in android studio where I run the project and it kicks up an error. There isn't really much else I know, but here's the full error:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\John\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\instant-run\AndroidManifest.xml:44: error: resource string/google_maps_key (aka com.example.john.myapplication:string/google_maps_key) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.

Command: C:\Users\John\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\400d656be4460564aa03c7fb5fa4f8bf\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        -I\
        C:\Users\John\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\John\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\instant-run\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\John\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_main_apk_resources\debug\instantRunMainApkResourcesDebug\out\main_resources\resources_ap\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        -0\
        apk\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

It occurred [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxQSU.png).
Please help!

Comment: By the way it is a google maps project, if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have something like this in your Android Manifest:

```
meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key"
```

You need to add that string to your app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key"> COPY THE VALUE FROM GOOGLE CLOUD PLATFORM </string>
</resources>
```

You can follow [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup) to get the API key.